# Data not showing up in Kibana dashboard but is being sent by filebeat

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, filebeat

I am using filebeat to send logs to logstash, do processing and then send to ES.

But somehow the log in being sent by filebeat but it gets lost before reaching anywhere in ES or kibana.

I have set log level to debug on filebeat to check if logs are being sent and it is showing correct logs being.

It is almost like logs are being sent to a black hole and they never appear anywhere at all.

Here's the example of a single log entry being sent from filebeat:

```
2018-07-08T09:57:40.626-0500    DEBUG   [publish]   pipeline/processor.go:275   Publish event: {
  "@timestamp": "2018-07-08T14:57:35.626Z",
  "@metadata": {
    "beat": "filebeat",
    "type": "doc",
    "version": "6.2.4"
  },
  "offset": 29282968,
  "message": "08 Jul 2018 10:57:33,290  INFO IpdrImportJob:48 - \tDEBUG\n08 Jul 2018 10:57:33,290  INFO IpdrImportJob:48 - \tRemoved bogus entries: 0\n08 Jul 2018 10:57:33,292  INFO IpdrImportJob:48 - \tFinished processing of 204.186.87.8-20180708093814.csv in: 0h:4m:15s (143 recs/s)\n08 Jul 2018 10:57:33,293  INFO IpdrImportJob:365 - Processing 204.186.87.8-20180708093814.csv complete",
  "source": "/opt/openvault/server/logs/onm-server.log",
  "tags": [
    "onm-server-voip-records"
  ],
  "prospector": {
    "type": "log"
  },
  "beat": {
    "name": "ptd",
    "hostname": "ptd",
    "version": "6.2.4"
  }
}
```

Nothing is reported in ES or logstash logs.

Comment: you need to share with us is the log in filebeat in order we can get a clue what is the root of your problem - as well what is your fielbeat and logstash config?

Comment: This is solved. On the output side of LS configuration I was creating custom index based on tags and I guess the condition I was trying to matching multiple tags was not working. The condition was something like `if tags in ['tag1','tag2','tag3']`. Instead when I tried `if "tag1" in [tags] or "tag2" in [tags]`, it worked.